# JavaFX: getWidth() and getLayoutBounds() return 0

Tags: java, javafx, layout, fxml

[image]

Hello guys,
I am developping a simple editor to create some use cases using JavaFX. Now, when I want to connect two nodes to each other, I would like to give that link a name. Currently the idea is to put a label into an anchorPane and center this pane in the middle of the link. 
The problem is, that neither the getWidth()- nor the getLayoutBounds() function return correct results, but 0 in all cases. 
How can I figure out the width of that anchorPane?
Thanks for all answers!

//Java code

```
public class Link extends AnchorPane{

    public Link() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(
            getClass().getResource("../view/Link.fxml")
        );

        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this); 
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try { 
            fxmlLoader.load();

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public void bindAnchorPane(DraggableNode source, DraggableNode target){
        //Middlepoint X source and target node
        NumberBinding middleX = Bindings.add(Bindings.divide(source.layoutXProperty(), 2), Bindings.add(Bindings.divide(target.layoutXProperty(), 2), source.getWidth() / 2.0));
        //Middlepoint Y source and target node
        NumberBinding middleY = Bindings.add(Bindings.divide(source.layoutYProperty(), 2), Bindings.add(Bindings.divide(target.layoutYProperty(), 2), source.getWidth() / 2.0));

        //X position of the anchorPane
        //Middlepoint X - anchor.getWidth()/2
        NumberBinding coordX = Bindings.subtract(middleX, anchor_link_label.getWidth()/2;
//        Bounds bounds = anchor_link_label.getLayoutBounds();
//        NumberBinding coordX = Bindings.subtract(middleX, (bounds.getMaxX() - bounds.getMinX()));

        anchor_link_label.layoutXProperty().bind(coordX);
        anchor_link_label.layoutYProperty().bind(middleY);

    }
}
```

//FXML file

```
<fx:root stylesheets="@application.css" type="Pane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
       <children>
            <CubicCurve fx:id="node_link" controlX2="50.0" controlY1="10.0" controlY2="10.0" endX="10.0" fill="#1f93ff00" stroke="BLACK" />
            <AnchorPane fx:id="anchor_link_label" managed="false">
                <Label fx:id="label_link" text="" onMouseClicked="#showTextField" visible="false" managed="false"/>
                <TextField fx:id="textField_link" minWidth="100" visible="true" managed="true"/>
            </AnchorPane>
       </children>
    </fx:root>
```

Answer (score 3):

At the time this code runs the height and width *are* zero since I'm guessing the node hasn't been laid-out yet.

if you want the `middleX`, `middleY`, and `coordX` bindings to update with the current width/height then you need to bind them to the width height properties/bindings instead of just the width/height at that one call you make "`source.getWidth() / 2.0`" when it is zero.

Try this:

```
// Middlepoint X source and target node
NumberBinding middleX = source.layoutXProperty().divide(2)
        .add(target.layoutXProperty().divide(2).add(source.widthProperty().divide(2)));

// Middlepoint Y source and target node
NumberBinding middleY = source.layoutYProperty().divide(2)
        .add(target.layoutYProperty().divide(2).add(source.heightProperty().divide(2)));

// X position of the anchorPane
// Middlepoint X - anchor.getWidth()/2
NumberBinding coordX = middleX.subtract(anchor_link_label.widthProperty().divide(2));

// anchor_link_label.layoutXProperty().bind(coordX);
// anchor_link_label.layoutYProperty().bind(middleY);

// To avoid binding and getting a "bound value cannot be set" error
// you can just use listeners instead.

// However, this is slightly hackish, since you are re-laying-out this child 
// after the parent tries to lay it out already.
// What you probably should do is define a parent that overrides 
// `layoutChildren()` and determines how to layout this node.

// Here are the listeners:
coordX.addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    anchor_link_label
        .setLayoutX(
            newVal.doubleValue() - anchor_link_label.getLayoutBounds().getMinX());
    });

middleY.addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    anchor_link_label
        .setLayoutY(
             newVal.doubleValue() - anchor_link_label.getLayoutBounds().getMinY());
    });
```

A possible alternative would be to use an `HBox` as your parent and setting the alignment to center, rather than using a generic `Pane`, since it seems all you really want it to do is to put the label in the center of the pane.

Comment: Hello xtratic, thanks for that quick answer! I have tried that but the problem still remains: anchor_link_label.widthProperty() also returns 0.

Comment: What is setting `anchor_link_label`s width/height (what is it's parent)? I'll need to see more code.

Comment: The parent node is an object of my custom class "Link" which extends AnchorPane. The method bindAnchorPane() is called in that class.

Comment: I think `managed="false"` means that the parent will not layout this child, thus it will never be given a width/height. Try setting `<AnchorPane fx:id="anchor_link_label" managed="true">` or just omitting it since managed is the default I think. Why `managed="false"` anyway?

Comment: Thats a good point thanks. But it needs to be false, otherwise I get the Exception "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: AnchorPane.layoutX : A bound value cannot be set." in that line where I try to bind the layoutProperty from the AnchorPane

Comment: Nonetheless, you are correct! If I change the managed flag to true, the size is not 0 anymore. I guess there is no other solution for that.

Comment: I'll write up your solution, just a min.

Comment: @decman edited: you can use listeners to get around binding. But this is slightly hackish. The core of what you want is a parent that lays out its child in the way that you want, and I believe the most correct way to do this is to define that parent and override `layoutChildren()`.

Comment: Thanks buddy thats awesome! I really appreciate your effort!

Comment: @decman No problem, JavaFX can certainly be frustrating, I've been learning it over the past couple weeks and luckily have the experience to solve these types of issues.

Comment: Hey buddy, me again. I hope you are still following this post. Next problem just appeared: When I click the label, a textfield appears where I can edit the name. If I press enter, the results get written back to the label and the textfield hides back again. Same problem here: I cannot receive the widthProperty from the label, since it has not been drawn yet. Is there any solution to change nodes and immediately gain acces to their new characteristics?